# Can't use more modern for loop with vector of derived class object. Why?

Tags: c++, for-loop, stdvector

I have a base class and some derived classes.  I generate a few objects of the derived classes, cast to the base class, and push them into a vector.  I can iterate over the vector using an int index, but not using an iterator.  Any idea why?

Given...

```
class Product
{
protected:
    char product_id;
    char size_id;
public:
    void Print();
    virtual ~Product() = 0;
};

class ProductASmall : public Product { public: ProductASmall(); };
class ProductAMedium : public Product { public: ProductAMedium(); };
class ProductALarge : public Product { public: ProductALarge(); };
```

...and...

```
vector<unique_ptr<Product>> products;

unique_ptr<ProductFactory> product_factory = ProductFactory::GetProductFactory(ProductType::A);
products.push_back(product_factory->CreateSmall());
products.push_back(product_factory->CreateMedium());
products.push_back(product_factory->CreateLarge());
```

Why does this work...

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++)
{
    products[i]->Print();
}
```

...and this fails...

```
for (auto p : products)
{
    p->Print();
}
```

...with error...

```
Error (active)  E1776   function "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx> &) [with _Ty=Product, _Dx=std::default_delete<Product>]" (declared at line 3433 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\memory") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

Comment: You are trying to copy a vector element into `p` in each iteration, which is not possible (`unique_ptr` doesn't support copy semantics). Easy fix: `auto & p` or, better if sufficient, `const auto & p`.

Comment: Your comment and the linked article both answer nicely.  Thanks!

Comment: Shall I delete mine to kill noise?

Comment: Just self answer.  Or leave it as is.  Duplicates are better than deletes, as it gives google juice to target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from @Daniel Langr:

> You are trying to copy a vector element into p in each iteration,
> which is not possible (unique_ptr doesn't support copy semantics).
> Easy fix: auto & p or, better if sufficient, const auto & p.